# Generating CFG for a Language

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

Consider the language  `{anbmcp | n <= p OR m <= p}` , create a CFG for this language.
I have started this with `S -> aA | aB`, but am unsure how I should go about defining A or B. The "OR" seems quite difficult to incorporate into the language's definition as it doesn't seem necessary to track both n and m and compare them against p, yet I don't know which one I want to track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to maintain that constraint, for every 'a' you need to add a 'c'. Similarly for every 'b' you should add a 'c'.

> `A -> aAC | aC | B`
>
> `B -> bB | bC`
>
> `C -> cC | c`

I could be wrong here. But that's how you should think while creating a CFG.